# openCV Mat access violation in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, mat, fits

I am getting "Exception thrown at 0x00007FFF428944E0 (opencv_world343d.dll) in ... .exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000023339631FB8." I have read some "access violation reading location" posts and topics but I think I allocate and initialize memory correctly, which seems to be the issue most often.

My code contains a "loadfits" function that loads a 16bit grayscale picture and stores it in a openCV cv::Mat. The function works - right at the end before the return statement, I can show or save the image and everything works perfectly, inside the function. But when I try to access and work with the cv::Mat in main(), I get the access violation error.

```
#define DFTtypeCV CV_64FC1
#define PICtypeCV CV_16UC1  //16bit grayscale image

Mat loadfits(std::string path)
{
ifstream streamIN(path, ios::binary | ios::in);
vector<char> celyobraz_8(fitsSize*fitsSize * 2, 0);
streamIN.read(&celyobraz_8[0], fitsSize*fitsSize * 2);

... //some code

Mat fits_PICTURE_Mat = Mat(fitsSize, fitsSize, PICtypeCV, &celyobraz_8[0], Mat::AUTO_STEP);

showimg(fits_PICTURE_Mat, "fitsRaw"); //shows the correct image
return fits_PICTURE_Mat;    //returns the same image
}
```

Then I use this function to initialize and work with with a cv::Mat in main()

```
Mat picZERO(fitsSize, fitsSize, PICtypeCV);
Mat picZEROd(fitsSize, fitsSize, DFTtypeCV);

picZERO = loadfits(path);
picZERO.convertTo(picZEROd, DFTtypeCV); //I get the error here
```

I thought I am gonna be able to solve this bug easily since I have the correct data right before the function return statement, but can't seem to figure it out.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I assume `celyobraz_8` is local variable in `loatfits` (I guess a `std::vector`)? It would be really useful if you provided a proper [mcve], so we don't have to guess.

Comment: The thing to keep in mind is that when you construct a `cv::Mat` this way, it doesn't own the pixel data array, so you have to assure that the array exists at least as long as the `cv::Mat` wrapping it.

Comment: @DanMašek yes, celyobraz_8 is indeed a vector, edited my post and added more relevant code

Comment: Yeah, so the issue is that the vector goes out of scope at the end of `loatfits`, but your `cv::Mat` still points to where the vector data used to be. If you don't mind copying the whole image, just do `return fits_PICTURE_Mat.clone();`

Comment: It worked, didn't know, that this cv::Mat construction only refers to some data and does not own it. Thanks!

Comment: @DanMašek, If the problem is that the `cv::Mat` instance that does the initial allocation remains the owner of the memory (i.e. no reference-counting), why isn't there the same problem when the temporary returned by `clone` destructs? I worry that if `clone` makes it work for @Zdeny's code, it may just be [NRVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision#Return_value_optimization) or some other lucky fragile code-arrangement.

Comment: @KeithRussell The `Mat` class is capable of behaving both ways -- it can either observe a pointer to some buffer (as in the case of this function), or it can allocate one and own it, in which case it does reference counting. Calling `clone` performs a deep copy, which allocates a new buffer that's reference counted. Assignment is a shallow copy -- in the owning case reference count increases, in non-owning case it just copies the pointer it observes. | See https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d6/d6d/tutorial_mat_the_basic_image_container.html for more details.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem. In my case, the solution was to remove the link to opencv_world343d.dll in release configuration. This file is only for debug mode.

(Initially, I followed this instruction http://shailendra.me/tutorial/add-opencv-to-visual-studio-c++-project/ )